# Not able to wireless project (mirror) from Laptop to TV

Tags: tv, projector, screencasts

I have a Dell Win 8.1 Core i5 Laptop - I am trying to connect wireless to my TV, to use it as a projector...unsuccessfully. :(

I have a Samsung 32' Smart TV (Manual can be found here :http://www.samsung.com/in/support/model/UA32J4300ARLXL/). Pretty basic TV but has a built in wireless adapter. Connects with no hitches to wifi routers, mobile devices et al.

But this is not working with the laptop. This is how I try to connect from the Laptop::
I use the right swipe screen options -Devices-Project-Add a wireless display-"Selecting my TV"
What happens next is that the TV detects some device trying to connect on screen mirror - shows a "loading" scroll bar..great.. meanwhile as seen during projections, my laptop starts adjusting the screen...awesome... then suddenly it all stops, TV shows screen mirroring has ended!

I tried to figure the projection settings (Display options for multiscreen on windows OS) where is shows the number of connected screens. I start the process again (explained above), for a brief instance the laptop detects a second screen..heck i moved the mouse frantically and saw it on tthe TV screen! then it all stops!

Can anyone help me with this? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check the **windows firewall settings** for the "**wireless display adapter.**" Make sure both **public and private** boxes are checked to **allow it through the firewall.** I tried everything I could find on Google, but this **finally solved the problem**... Hope this helps!